# How to disable pdf-viewer built-in in chromedriver

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I am using Ruby, Watir and Chromedriver. And I need to disable the pdf-viewer when clicingk in a pdf link in my web tests. I tried, without any luck, a lot of different settings like:

```
prefs = {
    plugins: {
      plugins_disabled: ['Chrome PDF Viewer']
    },
    download: {
      prompt_for_download: false,
      directory_upgrade:   true,
      default_directory:   '/pdf_downloads'
    }
}
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :prefs => prefs
```

Or

```
prefs= {
  'profile' => {
  'default_content_setting_values' => {'automatic_downloads' => 1}
  }
}
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :prefs => prefs
```

Could anyone give some tips or advice?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the PDF viewer by enabling the always_open_pdf_externally setting. This will cause the file to be downloaded instead.

```
prefs = {
  plugins: {
    always_open_pdf_externally: true
  }
}
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, prefs: prefs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the PDF viewer but you can cycle through the windows and close the PDF window.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

The context of my test was to check if the pdf available in the web is the same as the pdf of reference. At the end to check if the pdf downloaded was the same as the pdf taken as reference, my best option was to read both contents and compare between them. I create a simpe and small function

```
def pdf_text(url_file_input)
  pdf_text = Array.new
  io = open(url_file_input)
  reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)
  reader.pages.each do |page|
   pdf_text << page.text
  end
  return pdf_text
end
```

And later comparing using expect:

```
expect(pdf_text("url_to_file.pdf")).to eql(pdf_text('path_to_file.pdf'))
```